# Regex for URLs outside square bracket in text PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this:

```
[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

It matches for:

```
www.example.com 
http://example.com.nz 
example.com
http://www.example.com?2rjl6
example.com/first/second
https://example.us.edi?34535/534534?dfg=g&fg

etc...
```

I want no match if any of the above URLs are enclosed in square brackets [ ] like this:

```
[www.example.com]
[http://example.com.nz]
etc...
```

The text is long and may or may not contain more than one URL, spaces, line breaks, and so on.

> e.g.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [http://example.com.nz] llamcorper et lacus. Morbi sodales convallis lectus a efficitur: **example.com/first/second** vitae nisl placerat.
>
> Fusce non ipsum a augue **http://example.com.nz**  **http://www.example.com?2rjl6** aculis augue. Nullam eu nulla lectus.

In this case there should be only 3 matches.

I tried adding:

```
(?![^\[]*\])
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Can you help me with this or recommend another approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match from an opening till closing square bracket, and then  make use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) using php.

You might also shorten the pattern a bit. You have the whole first part in a character class `[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]` but you can move the square bracket to before the `[a-z`,

And as you can write a-zA-Z0-9_ as `\w`, you can shorten the character class a bit starting with `[\w`

If you choose a different delimiter than `/` like `~` you don't have to escape the backslash.

```
\[[^][]*](*SKIP)(*F)|(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?[\w@:%.+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b[\w-@:%+.~#?&/=]*
```

**Explanation**

- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `(?:https?://)?` Optionally match the protocol
- `(?:www\.)?` Optionally match `www.`
- `[\w@:%.+~#=]{2,256}` Repeat 2-256 times any of the listed in the character class
- `\.[a-z]{2,6}\b` match a dot and 2-6 chars a-z followed by a word boundary
- `[\w-@:%+.~#?&/=]*` Optionally match what is listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQHESO/1)

Comment: Works like a charm,  thanks. Just one thing, in PCRE it works without touching anything but in PCR2 I have to escape `-` in `[\w-@:%+.~#?&/=]*` otherwise it gives me an error regardless of the delimiter.

Comment: @Dr_Kramer You are correct about that, the `-` should be at the start or at the end of the character class in that that case.